# Unknown code being added to HTML template when running local server

Tags: python, django, gulp, dropzone.js

I was building a profile picture feature, it was working fine so I left it for a while, probably a week. I came back to it and ran the local server, but when I do there's a few lines that appear in the console. But do not exist on the source file.

Source file:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    autoProcessQueue : false,
    paramName: 'uploaded_image',
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drag and drop files or click here to upload picture",

    init: function() {
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submitBtn")
        myDropzone = this;
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });
        // Automatically overwrites file so the user can only upload one
        this.on("addedfile", function() {
            document.getElementById('submitBtn').style.visibility = "visible";
        });

        this.on('addedfile', function(){
            if (this.files[1]!=null){
                this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
            }
        });
    }
};
</script>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="picModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close"></span>
    <form action="{% url 'profile_test' %}" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone">{% csrf_token %}
        <!-- submit button stays hidden by default, until user selects a picture -->
        <button id='submitBtn' type='submit' class='pic-submit-button' style='visibility: hidden;'> Submit </button>
        <input id='submit-all' type='file' name='uploaded_image'/>
            {{form}}
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now the code I'm seeing when I run the server is only a few lines, and it's in the HTML that creates the modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="picModal" class="modal" style="display: block;">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close"></span>
    <form action="/api/profile_test/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="my-dropzone"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="WDMihPq0zDhDQGaWxSFYyvxjtmxUxsBMpAzcDqVxDGUZj11O8wtqbCfCie1m81Tf">
        <!-- submit button stays hidden by default, until user selects a picture -->
        <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="pic-submit-button" style="visibility: hidden;"> Submit </button>



       *****<input id="submit-all" type="file" name="uploaded_image">
            <label for="id_user">User:</label><select name="user" id="id_user">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="2">Brian</option>

  <option value="3">Charles</option>

</select>
<label for="id_img">Img:</label><input type="file" name="img" required="" id="id_img">
    <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drag and drop files or click here to upload picture</span></div></form>
  </div>

</div>*****
```

The last chunk of code I put stars around is the code that is unknown to me. The Django project I cloned was using gulp, I talked to my friends and they said that it may have something to do with it, maybe it's doing something with Dropzone.js?. But why would it inject a random dropdown menu listing users in Django? I didn't use gulp myself because I just wanted to develop the feature, but that may have been a mistake.

Comment: looks like forms generated automatically from your models. check models.py file.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Django is expanding `{{form}}` to be the actual html code for the form.  (What else did you expect it to do?)

Comment: omg im so dumb, I don't remember why I put that there. But it doesn't look like I need it. I must have been playing around with it a while ago. But I'm not sure why it would display a dropdown menu. My `form` context is an `ImageUplaodForm`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the

```
{{form}}
```

is causing this issue.